# Executing a python script from another python script using subprocess call/popen

Tags: python, shell, wxpython

I am having an issue executing a python script from a different python script:

```
filePath = "C:\Desktop\TestScripts\test.py"
####subprocess.call(filePath, shell = True)

child = subprocess.Popen(filePath, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   while True:
        out = child.stderr.read(1)
        if out == '' and child.poll() != None:
           break
        if out != '':
           sys.stdout.write(out)
           sys.stdout.flush()
```

When I execute this, I am getting:

```
'C:\Desktop\TestScripts\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I couldn't interpret the above error. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the error is saying that the file `'C:\Desktop\TestScripts\'` could not be found. The filename is getting truncated because  `'\t'` is a TAB character.

```
In [156]: print('C:\Desktop\TestScripts\test.py')
C:\Desktop\TestScripts  est.py
```

Use the [raw string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) `r'C:\Desktop\TestScripts\test.py'` instead.

```
In [157]: print(r'C:\Desktop\TestScripts\test.py')
C:\Desktop\TestScripts\test.py
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't observe that.